# Disable default folders from being created with new user

Tags: raspberry-pi-os-bookworm

When I create a new user in Raspberry Pi OS Bookworm 64-bit full (Desktop), it also creates default folders in the home directory: Bookshelf, Desktop, Documents, Downloads, Music, Pictures, Public, Templates, Videos. These aren't listed in /etc/skel and I don't want any of them. How can I disable this behavior? This doesn't happen in Raspberry Pi OS Lite.

Comment: Don't use an OS with Desktop!

Comment: Are you using [`adduser` or `useradd`?](https://linuxhandbook.com/useradd-vs-adduser/)  -  or something else?

Comment: I'm not a user of the RpiOS desktop, but I believe this is the kind of thing a [DE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment) does, possibly separately from the actual user creation (the first time the user logs in via the [DM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_display_manager) that stuff is added to home).

Answer (score 0):

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1064544/how-are-the-default-user-folders-in-the-home-created-for-a-new-user

This behavior is configured in `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults`.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question about RaspiOS. RaspiOS and Ubuntu are completely different unlike RaspiOS and RaspiOS Lite.

Comment: It probably is more or less correct though.  XDG stuff is essentially pan-distro.